# Montar PDF via website

Tags: javascript, html5, api, web-service, aplicação-web

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto de um site, onde ele recebe informações via `input` e retorna um *PDF* formatado com essas informações.

Penso que uma solução seria desenvolver uma *API* passando as informações via *JSON* ou *XML*, montar o arquivo e retornar via download, mas não sei muito bem se é a melhor forma ou prática. Então, como pegar essas informações e montar um *PDF* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes usar o [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) para gerar pdf através do HTML.
Para o tal tens que:

1. Criar a tal estrutura em html que deseja imprimir no formato PDF;
2. Preencher dinamicamente a estrutura com a informação do input;
3. E, depois gerar o pdf.

Exemplo:

```js
  
window.html2canvas = html2canvas;

  document.getElementById("gerar_pdf").addEventListener("click", myFunction);

  function myFunction(event) {
    var userName = document.getElementById('userName').value; // Busca o nome no input
    document.getElementById('es_userName').innerHTML = userName; // Preenche a estrutura

    setTimeout(_=> {
      var node = document.getElementById('estruturaParaPDF'); // Busca o node

      print(node);
      
   /* Primeiro gerar o canvas para evitar o erro  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54126963/jspdf-html2canvas-not-loaded-while-using-new-html-method]*/

      function print(html) {
        const filename = 'pdfName.pdf';
        const doc = new jsPDF();

        html2canvas(html, {
          onrendered: function(canvas) {
            var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
            var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', [297, 210]);
            doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 10, 10);
            doc.save(filename);
          }
        })

      }
    })
  }
```

```html
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/jspdf@latest/dist/jspdf.min.js"></script>

<form id="form_id">
  Introduz nome do utilizador: <input type="text" id="userName" value="" placeholder="">
</form>

<button id="gerar_pdf">Gerar PDF</button>

<div>
  <div id="estruturaParaPDF">
    <h1 style="color: red"> Gerado de HTML para PDF </h1>
    <h4> Nome do utilizador: <span id="es_userName"></span> </h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado. Desta forma fica mais fácil do que imaginava.