# PDF gerado fica em branco com Jspdf

Tags: javascript, jspdf

**Corpo do html:**

```
<div id="content">  
  <div class="table-responsive" >   
    <table class="table">';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
{  
  $output .= '
  <div class="modal-body">  
  <div class="table-responsive"> 
  <form id="insert_form">
  <div class="form-group input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">
  <span class="fa fa-code"></span>
  </span>
  <input type="text" id="codigo1" name="codigo" value="'.$row["codigo"].'" class="form-control" readonly="true"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
  </span>
  <input type="text" id="nome1" name="nome" value="'.$row["nome"].'" class="form-control" readonly="true"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">
  <span class="fa fa-birthday-cake"></span>
  </span>
  <input type="text" id="data1" name="data" value="'.$row["data"].'" class="form-control" readonly="true"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">
  <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
  </span>
  <input type="text" id="admissao1" name="admissao" value="'.$row["admissao"].'" class="form-control" readonly="true"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>
  </span>
  <input type="text" id="dependencia1" name="dependencia" value="'.$row["Dependencia"].'" class="form-control" readonly="true"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">
  <span class="teste">Ajudas Técnicas</span>
  </span>
  <div class="funkyradio">
  <div class="grid-container">
  <div class="funkyradio-success grid-item">
  <input type="checkbox" name="tecnicas" id="tecnicas2" Value="Sim" ' . ( ($row["tecnicas"]=='Sim') ? 'checked' : '' ) .' readonly="true">
  <label for="tecnicas">Sim</label>
  </div>
  <div class="funkyradio-primary grid-item">
  <input type="checkbox" name="tecnicas" id="tecnicas3" Value="Não" ' . ( ($row["tecnicas"]=='Não') ? 'checked' : '' ) .' readonly="true">
  <label for="tecnicas1">Não </label>
  </div>
  </div>
  <span class="input-group-addon">
  <span>Qual/Quais</span>
  </span>
  </div>
  </span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="qual1" name="qual" value="'.$row["qual"].'" class="form-control" readonly="true">
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer" >
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button> 
  <a type="button" name="edit" id="'.$row["Id"].'" data-toggle="modal" href="#add_data_Modal" class="btn btn-primary edit_data">Editar</a>                       
  </div>
  </form>                    
  </div>
  </div>                
  ';  
}
  $output.= '     
  </table> 
  </div>           
  </div> 
  ';
```

**Script:**

```
<script>
  function demoFromHTML() {
    var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
    source = $('#content')[0];
    specialElementHandlers = {
      '#bypassme': function (element, renderer) {
        return true
       }
    };
    margins = {
      top: 80,
      bottom: 60,
      left: 40,
      width: 522
    };
    pdf.fromHTML(
      source, 
      margins.left, 
      margins.top, {
        'width': margins.width, 
        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
      },
      function (dispose) {
        pdf.save('Test.pdf');
      }, 
      margins
    );
  }
</script>
```

**Aqui tenho o botão para gerar o pdf:**

```
<button class="btn btn-info" onclick="javascript:demoFromHTML();">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span>
</button>
```

Gera o pdf, mas o pdf fica em branco, não recebe os dados do html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta isso essa soluçao:

1. Transformar o html em `canvas` usando o [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) (Para evitar erro tipo [este](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54126963/jspdf-html2canvas-not-loaded-while-using-new-html-method]))
2. Transformar o `canvas` em imagem
3. E por fim a imagem em PDF

```js
function demoFromHTML() {

  const html_source = document.getElementById('employee_detail'); // O id do elemento que contém o Html que quer imprimir. 
  const filename = 'Test.pdf';


  html2canvas(html_source).then(function(canvas) {
    let imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

    let pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4'); // Essas demissões [297, 210] correspondem a um A4 

    // addImage(imageData, format, x, y, width, height, alias, compression, rotation) 
    // x: Coordenada (em unidades declaradas no início do documento PDF) contra a borda esquerda da página 
    // y: Coordenada (em unidades declaradas no início do documento PDF) contra a borda superior da página 
    pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 10, 10);
    pdf.save(filename);
  })

}
```

Para mais informações sobre o metódo `addImage` consulte a [documentação](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/module-addImage.html#~addImage)

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda. Estou a utilizar a solução que apresentou, mas depois como chamo esse exemplo que colocou no botão para gerar o pdf?

Comment: @Bruno vou já editar o codigo para a cautelar essa questão.

Comment: só mais uma coisa, nesta linha `const html_source = document.getElementById('content');` posso usar o id do form, certo?

Comment: Sim! Pode usar o id do formulário caso seja o elemento que deseja imprimir em PDF

Comment: @Bruno Veja está resposta [Montar PDF via website](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/381853/montar-pdf-via-website/381914#381914) talvez pode te ajudar.

Comment: implementei como disse e o resultado do pdf é este [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IE50w.png), mas se colocar a div com id=content gera o pdf em branco

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93960/discussion-between-cristiano-gilberto-joao-and-bruno).

Comment: Conseguiram alguma solução para esta situação ?